# inexact string search - short query string to huge database (blast?)

Tags: search, heuristics, string-search, blast

I have an OCR that recognises a few short query strings (4-12 letters) in a given picture. And I would like to match these recognised words against a big database of known words. I've already build a confusion matrix with the used alphabet from the most common mistakes and I tried to do a whole gotoh alignment against all words in my database and found (not surprinsingly) that this is too time consuming.

So I am looking for a heuristic approach to match these words to the database (allowing mismatches). Does anyone know of an available library or algorithm that could help me out?

I've already thought about using BLAST or FASTA but the way I understood it both are limited to the standard amino acid alphabet and I would like to use all letters and numbers.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: About how many words in the database do we speak? Are the exact matched or fuzzy matched? On suitable approach for many words and fuzzy matches is ngram search. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Huge database (>100k), short strings (~4-10 characters). I'm currently using java. Ngram search is pretty much what blast does, which I already looked into. I was hoping for a library that would help me out because I can hardly beleive this hasn't been done before but couldn't find any... In the end I programmed something pretty similar to blast.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but I've done some reading on bioinformatics (which aren't the topic but related). You could use suffix trees or related data structures to more-quickly search through the database. I believe currently the time required for construction of the tree is linear wrt database length, and time required for querying the tree is linear wrt length of query string, so if you have a lot of query strings that are relatively short this sounds like the perfect data structure for you. More reading can be found on the wikipedia page for suffix trees.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll try that. I ended up implementing my own blast version for now. But suffix tree is not exactly what I was hoping for, since as fas as I understand it is more for exact string matching, right?

Comment: It can be used for k-mismatch problems, much of the reading I've did on the topic were designed for this, though it does of course increase runtime